# div background behind/under body background

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that looks like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #cca900;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #borderimg {
            background: black;
            color: #cca900;
            border: 50px solid transparent;
            padding: 0px;
            -webkit-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
            -o-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
            /* Opera 11-12.1 */
            border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
        }
        div {
            border: 50px;
            padding: 22em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="borderimg">
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

I created a border around the div. The background is black for the whole page. The problem is, a part of the border image is hidden. Hidden by the background color of the div.
I tried adding

```
div {z-index: -1;}
```

to get the background of my div *behind* the borderimage, but that doesn't work. How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: try giving your body a z-index of 0 and div a z-index smaller than that of body

Comment: `div {position:relative; z-index:-1;}` it has to work with position together.

Comment: Your `div` doesn't have _any_ background color assigned, not sure what should or should not occlude what. The question is not clear to me. What do you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the property [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), you will find that it will only apply to elements that are positioned, so you will want to position your div with `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`.

Comment: Just for future reference, it's unadvisable to link to w3schools, and doing so [should be avoided](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to keep that in mind. It was the first thing to come up in a search and I usually only use them as a reference for some properties because its the quickest answer. Glad the rest of the information could be of help

Answer (score 1):

the border is set to be `transparent`. it has nothing to do with `z-index`

set css to: `border: 50px solid;`

like this

```css
body {
  color: #cca900;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#borderimg {
  background: black;
  color: #cca900;
  border: 50px solid;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
  -o-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
  /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
}
div {
  border: 50px;
  padding: 22em;
}
```

```html
<body id="borderimg">
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## The Answer

To answer you clearly with your solution, you will need to add `position: absolute;` to your CSS Properties.

## Example

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #cca900;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #borderimg {
            background: black;
            color: #cca900;
            border: 50px solid transparent;
            padding: 0px;
            -webkit-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
            -o-border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
            /* Opera 11-12.1 */
            border-image: url(img/rsz_gold_frame.jpg) 30 round;
        }
        div {
            position:absolute;
            border: 50px;
            padding: 22em;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="borderimg">
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

## Conclusion

I think this way everything will be working for you, because the z-index property specifies the stack order of a positioned element, so that you will need, as I said, `position:relative` property, since an element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.